# Error in the policyName when creating IAM Role by cloudformation

Tags: json, roles, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

This is the role snippet:

```
"InstanceRole": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [ {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
           "Service" : [ { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "Region2Principal", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },"EC2Principal" ] } ] },
        "Action"  : [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
      }]
    },
    "Path": "/",
    "Policies": [{
      "PolicyName": {"Fn::Join" : ["",["AWS::StackName","InstanceApi"] ] },
      "PolicyDocument": {
        "Statement": [{
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "*",
          "Resource": "*"
        }]
      }
    }]
  }
},
```

This is the error : `The specified value for policyName is invalid. It must contain only alphanumeric characters and/or the following: +=,.@_-`

The value of `AWS::StackName` I entered is `tmplt-stack` , and the generated policy name that gives error is : `tmplt-stack-InstanceApi-O7KF5OL0TA2Q`

I don't understand why cloudformation denies the name even that it only contain few characters of '-'  and it's allowed according to the error message and the rest are all alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the huge mistake I made when I used the pseudo parameter `AWS::StackName`, I didn't call it with `Ref`

```
"InstanceRole": {
  "Type": "AWS::IAM::Role",
  "Properties": {
    "AssumeRolePolicyDocument": {
      "Version" : "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [ {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
           "Service" : [ { "Fn::FindInMap": [ "Region2Principal", { "Ref": "AWS::Region" },"EC2Principal" ] } ] },
        "Action"  : [ "sts:AssumeRole" ]
      }]
    },
    "Path": "/",
    "Policies": [{
      "PolicyName": {"Fn::Join" : ["",[{"Ref":"AWS::StackName"},"InstanceApi"] ] },
      "PolicyDocument": {
        "Statement": [{
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "*",
          "Resource": "*"
        }]
      }
    }]
  }
},
```